# Inject Stub Collaborators In Globally Stubbed Class Using Spock and Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, dependency-injection, spock, stub

I'm rendering a GSP in a Spock unit test with Grails 2.4.4. The GSP has a number of custom taglibs, and many of them call external services. The problem is that I can't inject a stubbed service into those taglibs, and when I call the service, it's always null. Here's what I'm trying to get simplest case working:

```
@TestMixin(GroovyPageUnitTestMixin)
@Mock(FooTagLib)
class MyGspSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() {
        def barStub = Stub(BarService)
        def tagLibStub = GroovyStub(FooTagLib, global:true) {

        }
        tagLibStub.barService = barStub
    }
    def 'test method'() {
        when: String result = render('myView', model:[:])
        then: assert result != null
    }
}
```

Taglib:

```
class FooTagLib {
    static String namespace = "baz"
    BarService barService
    Closure<StreamCharBuffer> foo = { GroovyPageAttibutess attrs ->
        out << barService.something()
    }
}
```

_foo.gsp contents:

```
<baz:foo/>
```

I've also tried this:

```
FooTagLib.metaClass.barService = Stub(BarService) //also tried GroovyStub
```

I even tried putting a getter on the taglib and stubbing that, but it didn't work either:

In setup:

```
def barService = Stub(BarService)
GroovyStub(FooTagLib, global:true) {
    getBarService() >> barService
}
```

In taglib:

```
BarService barService
BarService getBarService() { return barService }
//....
out << getBarService().something()
```

**Finally**, the only thing that worked (with the getter) is this:

```
FooTagLib.metaClass.getBarService = { -> return Stub(BarService) }
```

But this seems like a really bad hack.

I'm not sure how I can inject a stubbed version of it into the taglib. In my mind at least one of these should work, but obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757855/how-to-mock-a-service-in-grails-taglib-unit-test

Comment: @topr The problem is that is for a tagLib under test, i.e. you have an instance of it that you are using. In this case I'm rendering a page, so I am not dealing with a specific taglib instance. There would be no way to since there could be any number of them in the page.

Comment: You call render in your test so there is probably controller invoked underneaths. Try maybe go with @TestFor for this controller then.

Comment: I am calling render but specifying a template (not a controller or view), so it is directly rendering the GSP. Even if it were invoking a controller, that still doesn't help being able to inject services into taglibs in the resulting GSP, only into the controller.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to Mock both the TagLib and the service within the TagLib. However, I believe that since you've mocked the TagLib itself, foo() is always going to return null. Why not just Mock you TagLib's foo() method with the result it should return when the GSP calls it? The TagLib should then have its own test for the foo method with a Mock for the result of barService.something().

Comment: I don't know the answer, but mixing Grails mocks (`@Mock(FooTagLib)`) and Spock mocks (`GroovyStub(FooTagLib, global: true)`) for the same class is suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would pass unit specs for the tagLib:

```
@TestFor(FooTagLib)
class FooTagLibSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
        // tagLib is available by default of above annotation is used
        tagLib.barService = Mock(BarService) {
            // Mock the service and stub the response
            1 * serviceMethod() >> { "Hello World Returns" }
        }
    }

    void "test something"() {
        expect: 'applying template would result in mocked response'
        applyTemplate('<baz:foo/>') == "Hello World Returns"
    }

    void "test taglib method call"() {
        expect:
        tagLib.foo() == "Hello World Returns"
    }
}

class FooTagLib {
    static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']
    static String namespace = "baz"    
    BarService barService

    Closure<StreamCharBuffer> foo = { attrs ->
        out << barService.serviceMethod()
    }
}

class BarService {
    def serviceMethod() { "Hello World" }
}
```

I hope I was able to meet the checkpoints you were looking for in your tests. You can also see spec is able to mock `BarService` without issues. Give a shout if you need for info.